# How can I summon a word between texts with CONCAT at BigQuery

Tags: concatenation, google-bigquery-storage-api

I tried to CONCAT 2 columns for easy read, 1 for the beginning of a trip and other for the end of the trip. I just want to put the word "to" between the result

I tried CONCAT (start_station_name, ' to ', end_station_name) AS route

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.